# no audio on Dell XPS 13 9310 (Intel Tiger Lake) with Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, sound, xps, firmware

Fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04, no audio at all, only "dummy output" in the available outputs in the audio settings.

I tried some of the solutions available online (adding options to `/etc/modprobe.d/alas-base.conf` or `/etc/default/grub`) and none worked.

Some info:

```
$ aplay -l

aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
```

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 audio
0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0c8] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0991]
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
```

Note that *audio works fine* with a fresh install of *Ubuntu 21* on the *same* laptop (I have dual boot). In this case, this is the output of `lspci`:

```
### Ubuntu 21.04 (works)
0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller [8086:a0c8] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Dell Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller [1028:0991]
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
```

**[This post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=260139) reports exactly my issue**, but it is archlinux and they solve it by updating the `sof-firmware`, which I do not know how to do in ubuntu.
An attempt in this direction with

```
sudo fwupdmgr update
```

did not solve it (BTW, `sudo fwupdmgr refresh` [fails](https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/issues/391)).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Clearly you need a newer kernel. Any reason for wanting to keep 18.04, released years before the hardware?

Comment: Legacy reasons...For my job I need to use a SW which depends on 18.04 and does not work on newer systems. Dont get me started on this :)
Can I install a newer kernel, maintaining the possibility of booting the current one?

Comment: If so you need to install a newer kernel that supports the integrated audio device (and hope that won't break said software) -or- live with it -or- use any cheap USB audio device until you sort out the "legacy software".

Comment: Updating the kernel did not work :(  Most recent versions are not compatible with libc. Some intermediate versions do make the speakers work (I see the sound card in the options) but not the microphone. Isn't there a way. in ubuntu, to update the sof-firmware package as they do in archlinux? (see the link in my question). Something like recompiling the kernel but replacing the sof-firmware with a more recent version